# How do I change the default Python version in my Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: python, macos

How do I change the default Python version used in my Mac Snow Leopard? I'm trying to switch from v2.5 to v3.0

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/225550/using-python-on-mac

Comment: Old thread, I know, but it comes out top of Google. Now there's pyenv, which is based on rbenv for Ruby https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Answer (score 3):

Is is not recommended to change the system Python installation on any system without any need.
Better install Python 3.X in a different location and adjust your $PATH as needed. The Python installation may be needed for further functionality under the hood. So leave it as it is and install arbitrary Python interpreters in a different location. Macports and Brew will do that automatically. If you compile Python yourself:

```
 configure --prefix=/path/to/my/python/installation.
```

Comment: That's true that you should absolutely not change the system Python installation.  But if you install Python 3 from source, it will not overlap with the system Python, even if you made the mistake of configuring into `/usr/bin` et al since all of the Python 3 files installed are designed to not conflict with Python 2 names, i.e. they all have a `3` in them.  Even better on Mac OS X is to configure Python framework (`--enable-framework`) builds which allow multiple minor versions of Python 2's and/or Python 3's to co-exist easily.

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a symlink to the desired version.

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
sudo rm Current
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.0 Current
```

This removes the current pointer to your default Python version and sets it to your 3.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the Apple-supplied Python man page (`man python`) on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), be aware that it is incorrect: Apple did not ship a Python 3.0 with 10.6.  You'll need to install a Python 3 version yourself.  The easiest way is to use a [binary installer from python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/).  But you can also use MacPorts or Homebrew or do it yourself.  Also, be aware that support for Python 3.0 was dropped immediately with the release of Python 3.1.  Python 3.2 is now current.  However you install it, the Python 3 interpreter will be available as either `python3` or `python3.2`.  It does not conflict with Python 2 (`python`).  You may need to adjust your shell PATH though.  The python.org installer will do that for you; follow the installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: `defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 3.2` in a terminal. Assuming you have 3.2 installed of course.

EDIT: As Neil Deily points out in his comment this only works with Python distributions shipped by Apple.

Comment: Have you tried that?  The `versioner` trick only applies to Apple's /usr/bin/python and the system-supplied Pythons.

Comment: I tried it to switch from 2.5 to 2.6, not other versions. IIRC I installed 2.6 from the package on python.org.

Comment: Apple ships a Python 2.6 and a Python 2.5 with OS X 10.6.  2.6 is the default. You can install a newer Python 2.6 from python.org but the `versioner` default has no affect on it.  It's a feature that was added by Apple to their `/usr/bin/python` front-end program.

Answer (score 0):

I would first install Xcode on my machine (it comes on the installation disc that came with your computer). Then run Software Update to bring it up to date (at least to the most-current free version).

Then, download the Python 3.x source code and extract it.  Do "./configure", "make" and "sudo make install" in that directory.  These will install the new Python installation in /usr/local/bin (and other nearby places).

If all goes well, /usr/local/bin/python will be a Python 3 interpreter you can use.  I would hesitate to overwrite the installed version of Python, since that might make trouble for python scripts shipped with the operating system.  I never install anything in /usr; I let Software Update take care of that.  For all the rest of my software needs, the "./configure ... make ... sudo make install" technique works very well on Snow Leopard once Xcode is installed.

Comment: Why build it yourself?  It's actually a bit tricky to get it done right.  There are binary installers and/or third-party package managers that handle all the messy details, like getting the right third-party libraries.

Comment: I agree, though, that you should make sure you have the Xcode development tools installed;  you'll need them for MacPorts or Homebrew or just to build a Python package with a C extension module. And, for Python purposes, you're better off sticking with Xcode 3 for now, not the new Xcode 4.  There can be added complications due to the dropping of PPC support in Xcode 4.

Comment: Fair comments; I have a lot built in /usr/local so it's the first thing I think of. For the questioner's case a package would probably be best. Ultimately building your own stuff is a useful skill to have IMO